Unable to delete default H2 Datasource in JBoss EAP 6.4 and use my MySQL Datasource as default datasource
I am having a challenge with JBoss EAP 6.4. I would like my application which is using EJB 2.x Entity Beans to use the mysql datasource that I added in the standalone.xml configuration.
I added a new MySQL Datasource in the standalone.xml configuration and I deployed the application and invoked my Entity Bean, it was defaulting to the H2 Datasource. I tried deleting the H2 datasource in the standalone.xml file and then my application couldn't start.
My application has EJB 2.x entity bean similar to this one:
ejb-jar.xml
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise
JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">
<ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <entity>
            <ejb-name>FoodEntity</ejb-name>
            <home>com.example.FoodEntityHome</home>
            <remote>com.example.FoodEntity</remote>
            <ejb-class>com.example.FoodEntityBean</ejb-class>
            <persistence-type>Container</persistence-type>

            <prim-key-class>java.lang.String</prim-key-class>

            <reentrant>false</reentrant>

            <cmp-version>2.x</cmp-version>
            <abstract-schema-name>FoodEntity</abstract-schema-name>

            <cmp-field>
                <field-name>id</field-name>
            </cmp-field>
            <cmp-field>
                <field-name>name</field-name>
            </cmp-field>
            <cmp-field>
                <field-name>description</field-name>
            </cmp-field>
        
            
            <primkey-field>id</primkey-field>

            <query>
                <query-method>
                    <method-name>findByName</method-name>
                    <method-params>
                        <method-param>java.lang.String</method-param>
                    </method-params>
                </query-method>
                <ejb-ql>SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT(p) FROM FoodEntity p WHERE
                    p.name =?1</ejb-ql>
            </query>
        </entity>
    </enterprise-beans>
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <method-permission>
            <unchecked/>
            <method>
                <ejb-name>FoodEntity</ejb-name>
                <method-name>*</method-name>
            </method>
        </method-permission>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>

Datasource configuration in standalone.xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X:3306/test</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>test</user-name>
                        <password>test</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
    </subsystem>    

I also have a ~/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/com/mysql/main/ directory with module.xml and the mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar driver.
module.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>

Can you kindly give me an idea on how I can tell my FoodEntity entity bean to use the MySQL Datasource instead of the default H2 Datasource. When I invoke my entity bean i can successfully create and retrieve FoodEntities from the H2 Datasource but now I want to be able to do that with my MySQL Datasource.
The reason why I am sticking to EJB 2.x entity beans is because I would like to have that backward compatibility support at the same time for new entities I will be using JPA and EJB 3.x annotations.
